# Header.php file for wordpress theme issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use a lightbox plugin on a custom theme but it does not work with a custom template. The themes regular 'default template' works fine for the lightbox. I am stuck using the custom template on some pages unfortunately.
I'm am looking for help in where to refine my search on solving this. 
So far my search has only brought up issues w/ the header.php file and including wp_head() Here is the code in this custom theme's header.php below:

```
    <?php
    if( empty($theme['opt-sitelogo']['url']) ) { ?>
        <style>
        /* style to place theme brick in admin bar */
        .newTheme-utility-bar-home {
          background-image: url("https://imageLinkurl.jpg");
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: contain;
          height: 60px;
        }
        .newTheme-utility-bar-primary-util {
          padding-top: 30px !important;
        }
        </style>
    <?php }

    wp_head();
    ?>
</head>
```

Any pointers on where to go from here would be very welcome! Thanks!!

*Edit* Here is the custom page template:

```
        <?php /* Name: Custom Content Page */ 
        require 'includes/styles.php'; get_header(); ?> 
        <?php if ( ! get_field('hide_title') ): ?> 
                            <div class='l-header'>
                            <div class='container<?php echo $fluid; ?>'>
                            <div class='page-lead'>                         
                            <h1><?php echo get_the_title() ?></h1>                      
                    <?php $ancestors = get_post_ancestors(get_the_ID());                            
                                $parent_post = get_post(end($ancestors)); 
                  if(get_field('section_description'))  { 
                      echo "<p>" . get_field('section_description') . "</p>"; 
                      } ?> 
                      </div></div></div>
                       <?php endif; ?>              
                       <section role="main" class='l-main'>                     
                         <?php  if ( have_rows('custom_content') || have_posts() ):                                 
                             while ( have_rows('custom_content',$post->ID) ) : the_row(); 
                             if( get_row_layout() == 'basic' ):     
                             include 'modules/basic.php'; 
                             endif;     
                             endwhile; 
                             else : endif; ?> 
                             </section> 
        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I would try either set inline styles or go with javascript

Comment: @pavlovich Thanks for the feedback - could you reference any links for using javascript in this case?